# On the solution of a olympics math problem.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, contest-math

The problem in question is

> The sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ of integers satisfies the following conditions:
>
> 1. $1\le a_j\le 2015$ for all $j\ge 1$;
> 2. $k+a_k\ne\ell+a_\ell$ for all $1\le k<\ell$.
>
> Prove that there exist two positive integers $b$ and $N$ such that $$\left|\sum_{j=m+1}^n(a_j-b) \right|\le 1007^2$$ for all integers $m$ and $n$ satisfying $n>m\ge N$.

I took a look at the first part of the solution given by the solver:

> Let $f(j)=j+a_j$, so $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is injective.
>
> **Lemma 1:** All sufficiently large integers are in the range of $f$.
>
> **Proof:** Assume not. So some $N$ (by the way, I will abuse the variable $N$ a lot and use it to stand for many different things) has over $9000$ of $1,\ldots,N$ not in the range. But $\{f(1),\ldots,f(N)\}\subseteq\{1,\ldots,N+2015\}$ has size $N$, so its intersection with $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ has size over $N-8500$, contradiction. End proof.

He proceeds by contradiction to prove his first Lemma, Aside for the fact that he uses a meme (over $9000$) in the math Olympics and I find it hilarious, 
I would like to know what he means by "has over $9000 \ 1, \dots, N$ not in the range".

As a negation of the lemma I would have said there exists a sufficiently large integer not in the range of $f$. I don't understand where these over $9000$ come from.

Also when he is comparing the two sets immediately below by "size" does he mean number of elements of the set?

(Original images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRNRC.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIQda.jpg).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim of the lemma is
$$ \exists n_0\forall n>n_0\colon n\in f[\mathbb N].$$
Its negation is
$$\tag1 \forall n_0\exists n>n_0\colon n\notin f[\mathbb N].$$
By picking $n_1>1$ with $n_1\notin f[\mathbb N]$ and  then recursively $n_{k+1}>n_k$ with $n_{k+1}\notin f[\mathbb N]$.
Then $n_1,n_2,\ldots, n_{9001}$ are all $\notin f[\mathbb N]$. You can then let $N=n_{9001}$. (And, yes, size refers to cardinality)

Comment: Could you explain to me even where the contradiction arises?